# AWS Load Balancer not being able to redirect to Auth0 login page

Tags: c#, .net-core, auth0, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm facing Auth0 sign in problem using a load balancer with a .NET core app. When I browse directly to port 80, it was able to redirect to Auth0 login page if the user's not authenticated. But when I browse via the load balancer (which is port 443), I'm getting the following error: `Internal Error: Missing Template ERR_CONNECT_FAIL`. I'm quite new with the hosting procedures and below is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name abdev.net *.abdev.net;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://0.0.0.0:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
        
        server_name abdev.net *.abdev.net;

        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://0.0.0.0:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
}
```

I tried to google it but it wasn't much help. I would greatly appreciate it if you would help me out with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. First, review your SSL settings.
Hope this helps.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name abdev.net *.abdev.net;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/your_domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your_domain.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://0.0.0.0:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```